# protractor-sync/page load issues

Tags: asynchronous, promise, protractor, synchronization

i am using protractor with cucumber-js to automate angular-js application. Have followed the structure, as specified in github cucumber-js framework.

features
step_definitions
support
pages

on executing the code through gulpfile feature file are calling the respective steps. While running protractor does not wait for page to load and keeps moving to further steps.

so here the questions is why protractor is not waiting for application to load even though i have specified browser.sleep(5000)
tried couple of methods:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
browser.get("appurl");
browser.sleep(5000);
browser.findElements(by.xpath("")).click();
```

tried with below code too, but no luck

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;
browser.get("appurl")
browser.sleep(5000)
browser.findElements(by.xpath("")).click();
```

I tried with expectedconditions with promises as well, but still no success.

I run script using gulpfile. Script works without throwing any errors, however no actions are simulated n finally browser gets killed.
not sure if i am missing any steps here.

please advise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`browser.ignoreSynchronization` is deprecated. If this variable set to `true` - protractor will NOT wait for angular.
For this purpose you can use [waitForAngularEnabled](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngularEnabled) .

I think you should remove this line `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;` and your error will go out.